# Rewrite to SEO friendly URLs for language negotiation with type-map files on plain html files using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, multilingual, clean-urls

When visiting the website www.example.com/ the visitor should be redirected to the correct language version, e.g. www.example.com/en for english and www.example.com/es for spanish.

My current implementation only works when visiting www.example.com/index.var and redirects to www.example.com/index.en. Now I want to rewrite this to www.example.com/en/

My implementation is based on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html.

### .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddHandler type-map .var
LanguagePriority en es de
ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
```

### index.var

```
URI: index; vary="language"

URI: index.en.html
Content-type: text/html
Content-language: en

URI: index.es.html
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-language: es

URI: index.de.html
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-language: de
```

Important: MultiViews are disabled

Looking forward to your great solutions.

---

to explain this a little more in detail...
Here's an example of my file structure:

```
   File                     should be rewritten or redirected to
 - index.var          -->   /
 - index.en.html      -->   /en/
 - index.es.html      -->   /es/
 - about.var          -->   /about
 - about.en.html      -->   /en/about
 - about.es.html      -->   /es/about
 - images/img_1.jpg   -->   /images/img_1.jpg
 - images/logo.var    -->   /images/logo.png (not a file)
 - images/logo.en.png -->   /en/images/logo.png
 - images/logo.es.png -->   /es/images/logo.png
```

*Rewriting of images and other resources is optional. It's only important to get rewriting of html files right.*

The Apache Documentation is a working example of this (using content negotiation).

Comment: Do you have a way to detect the browser's set language?

Comment: That's already done by type-maps (like index.var in my example).

Comment: Why did you disable multiviews?   I think that feature is supposed to handle this for you.

Comment: I have to disable it because it breaks a module that I run in a subdirectory. Furthermore multiviews will show different files under the same URL which is not good for SEO.

Comment: Why does `about.var` get redirected while `images/logo.var` does not?

Comment: You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: There is no way that a generic rule can figure out what extension to replace the `.var` files with,  it looks like you will have to redirect those individually.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution on Apache's SVN repository. (I haven't tested it yet)

[Configuration for Multilingual Site](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf.in?view=markup)
[Configuration for Multilingual Error Pages](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf.in?view=markup)
[Configuration with Languages and Encodings Setup](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf.in?view=markup)

The implementation here uses the .html extension for type-map files instead of .var. That means, if you want to use html files with the extension .html instead of .html.en, you have to replace

```
AddHandler type-map .html
```

with

```
AddHandler type-map .var
```

like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this in PHP. I'm not sure how to do it in htaccess.

I would make index.php :

```
<?php
header("Status: 200 OK");
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        include("index_fr.php");//include check session FR
        break;
    case "it":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        include("index_it.php");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        include("index_en.php");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        include("index_en.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
        break;
}
?>
```

Or if you want the redirect you can do:

```
    <?php
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    switch ($lang){
        case "en":
          header('Location: http://www.example.com/en/', true, 302);
    exit;
        case "es":
             header('Location: http://www.example.com/es/', true, 302);
  exit;
        case "de":
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/en/', true, 302);
  exit;       
        default:
            //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
            include("index_en.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
            break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This would only work if www.example.com/en/ would already show the content of www.example.com/index.en. Also it must work for all pages, not only for the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would use rewrite rules to issue 301 permanent redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on

# First handle the index.XX.html files
# where the language code is moved to the front directory
# and the index and html are removed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?([a-z]{2})/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?index\.([a-z]{2})\.html$ /$2/$1 [L,R=301]

# Then handle other file.XX.html files
# where the language code is moved to the front directory
# the file name is preserved, but the html is removed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?([a-z]{2})/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.([a-z]{2})\.html$ /$2/$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle all other file.XX.xyz
# where the language code is moved to the front directory
# and the file name and extension are preserved
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?([a-z]{2})/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.([a-z]{2})\.([a-z]+)$ /$2/$1.$3 [L,R=301]
```

This detects a two character language code using the regular expression `([a-z]{2})`.   You could instead using something like `(en|es|de)`  with a specific list of supported languages.  Doing so could reduce mistakes based on two digit codes used for something other than language (like maybe a gzipped javascript file: `.js.gz`.)  It would also allow you to expand the rules to include country info if needed (like `en-us`.)

All the rules have a `RewriteCond` that makes sure they don't apply in the language subdirectories.  That should help prevent infinite loops or other problems

The rules start with `/?` which consumes any leading slash so the rules can be used either in *.htaccess* or in an Apache *.conf* file.

The first rule makes the directory path preceding `index` optional using a question mark in the section `(.*/)?`.   It allows that rule apply to the root `index.XX.html` files.

I didn't put in a rule for the `.var` files because it sounds like you already have something in place for them.  You would need to continue to handle those files as you do now.

I tested these rules on my local Apache server by putting them in *.htaccess* and hitting the site with `curl`.   They seem to do the right thing:

```
$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/index.en.html'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/en/

$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/index.es.html'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/es/

$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/about.en.html'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/en/about

$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/about.es.html'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/es/about

$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/images/logo.en.png'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/en/images/logo.png

$ curl -s --head 'http://example.com/images/logo.es.png'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/es/images/logo.png
```

Comment: The URL is actually rewritten but it returns Error 404. And If I go to www.example.com/index it redirects first to /index.var and then to /en/index?lang=en&lang=en&lang=en&lang=en... and so on and results in a redirection loop. Thank you for your work and detailed explanations so far.